# Problem with parameter passing with arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, parameter-passing

This is a homework for my C programming class. The program calculates employee gross pay, tax pay, and net take home pay.

The program runs but it automatically ends saying "segmentation fault(core dumped)
The error message says:

line 127: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Prompt' from incompatible pointer type

line 13: note: expected 'char*' but argument is of type 'char*(*)[5]'

line 143: warning: passing argument 1 of 'PrintOutput' from incompatible pointer type

line 90: note: expected 'char*' but argument is of type 'char(*)[20][5]'

I don't quite understand the `int` type because I declared the `first_name` variable as an array in the `main()` function.
I don't understand the rest of the errors either.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Prompt(char* a, float* b, float* c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", &a[i]);
        if (strcmp(&a[i],"-1") == 0) {
            break;
        }

        printf("Enter hourly rate: ");
        scanf("%f", &b[i]);
        if (b[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }

        printf("Enter hours worked: ");
        scanf("%f", &c[i]);
        if (c[i] == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void GrossPay(float* grosspay, float* basepay, float* overtimepay,
              float* rate, float* hours)
{
    int i;

    if (hours[i] > 40) {
        overtimepay[i] = (hours[i] - 40) * (rate[i]) * 1.5;
        basepay[i] = rate[i] * hours[i];
        grosspay[i] = rate[i] * hours[i] + (hours[i] - 40) * (rate[i]) * 1.5;
    } else {
        overtimepay[i] = 0;
        basepay[i] = rate[i] * (hours[i]);
        grosspay[i] = basepay[i];
    }
    return;
}

float Taxes(float gross_pay[])
{
    int i;
    float taxes_owed[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        taxes_owed[i] = 0.2 * gross_pay[i];
    }
    return taxes_owed[5];
}

float CalculateTotal(float gross_pay[])
{
    int i;
    float total_pay = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        total_pay += gross_pay[i];
    }

    return total_pay;
}

void PrintOutput(char first_name[5], float* rate, float* hours,
                 float* gross_pay, float* base_pay, float* overtime_pay,
                 float* taxes_owed, float* net_pay, float* total_pay)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\nPay to: %s\n", &first_name[i]);
        printf("Hours worked: %5.1f\n", hours[i]);
        printf("Hourly rate: $%5.2f\n", rate[i]);
        printf("Gross pay: $%5.2f \n", gross_pay[i]);
        printf("Base pay: $%5.2f \n", base_pay[i]);
        printf("Overtime pay: $%5.2f\n", overtime_pay[i]);
        printf("Taxes paid: $%5.2f\n", taxes_owed[i]);
        printf("Net pay: $%5.2f\n\n", net_pay[i]);
    }
    printf("Total paid to all employees= $%5.2f\n", *total_pay);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    char first_name[20][5];
    float rate[5];
    float hours[5];
    float gross_pay[5];
    float base_pay[5];
    float overtime_pay[5];
    float taxes_owed[5];
    float net_pay[5];
    float total_pay;
    int i;


    Prompt(first_name, rate, hours);

    GrossPay(gross_pay, base_pay, overtime_pay, rate, hours);


    taxes_owed[5] = Taxes(gross_pay);

    total_pay = CalculateTotal(gross_pay);


    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        net_pay[i] = gross_pay[i] - taxes_owed[i];
    }


    PrintOutput(&first_name, rate, hours, gross_pay, base_pay, \
                overtime_pay, taxes_owed, net_pay, &total_pay);

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry I am very new at coding, never took a class on coding before and I am super confused right now, especially on parameter passing.

Comment: Go through the compiler errors one by one and fix them.  One line at a time, from the first error on down.  Once those are all fixed, try running the program again.  Don't bother trying to run a program that the compiler is warning you has bugs.

Comment: 'I don't quite understand the int type' - indeed, I don't understand either. What part of the error messages makes you think its something to do with an 'int type'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encountered problems like this first step would be using **compiler errors** and using **Debugger** to solve all the *syntax* error and logical error as well.
If you still facing error then you can post in here with source *code snippet* and *logs* file if you have any but make sure the question should not posted as **duplicate** so search before posting.

Now i have solved your code and could be found [here](https://ideone.com/Myq294) on `Ideone` and here is sample output as well.

```
Pay to: emp1
Hours worked:  20.0
Hourly rate: $10.00
Gross pay: $200.00 
Base pay: $200.00 
Overtime pay: $ 0.00
Taxes paid: $40.00
Net pay: $160.00


Pay to: emp2
Hours worked:  20.0
Hourly rate: $15.00
Gross pay: $300.00 
Base pay: $300.00 
Overtime pay: $ 0.00
Taxes paid: $60.00
Net pay: $240.00


Pay to: emp3
Hours worked:  25.0
Hourly rate: $15.00
Gross pay: $375.00 
Base pay: $375.00 
Overtime pay: $ 0.00
Taxes paid: $75.00
Net pay: $300.00
Total paid to all employees= $2375.00
```

And here are some notes about some misconception about **array and pointers.**

- **char*** a is single array but you declared name as *2d arra*y
  use char** means two level pointer for *2d array*.
- Passing *2d array* then you need **2 Indexes** *i* and *j* for *cols* and *rows*
  respectively.
- Always initialize local variables with **NULL** or **0**.
- Pointer and Array in function argument acts same so *arr[]* and *arr**
  are same argument but not in **local/global** variables.
- Scanf takes address of variables so we use **&** to pass address but for
  arrays we don't do that because Array itself acts as pointer so we
  write scanf("%d",arr+i) to access array with all elements.
- Always define constants with ***#define*** at top of declaration to re-use
  it in code.
- Don't try to return local array from function instead pass that as
  argument as **pass by reference**.

And use **pastebin.com** or **ideone.com** to paste your code if its too long in editor to show up.

Comment: Thank you so much!